# Create links from plain text in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string with some word separated by (,) like this

word1, word2,word3,word5, word5

I need a php function which take this string as a argument and output all of them as a link separated by (,) like this

```
<a href="?s=word1">word1</a>,<a href="?s=word2">word2</a>, <a href="?s=word3">word3</a>,<a href="?s=word4">word4</a>,<a href="?s=word5">word5</a>
```

Please someone help me to do that ...

Comment: What's with all the close votes? I suspect it's probably similar to other questions, but the close reason given is "not a real question"!?

Comment: Not a great way to welcome new users... nominated for re-opening.

Comment: He provided his problem and the expected result. That's pretty good. But he didn't try anything on his own - maybe because he does not know where to start. Try reading the PHP manual, or look up some tutorials: http://php.net/manual/en/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function makeString ($str) {
    $arr = explode(',',$str);
    $ret = '';
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        $ret .= '<a href="?s='.trim($v).'">'.trim($v).'</a>,';
    }

    return substr($ret,0,strlen($ret)-1);
}
```

(Untested)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this :

```
function makeLinks($input) {
   $arr = explode(',',$input);
   $output = "";
   foreach ($arr as $word) {
     $word = trim($word);
     $output .= '<a href="?s=' . $word . '">' . $word . '</a>,';
   }
    return substr($output, 0, -1); // remove the last ,
}
```

This uses [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to create an array from the string, then loops the array, trims the whitespace using [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). Using [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to remove the last `,` and returns the output

[Working example here](http://codepad.org/y9iEvyka)

Comment: You have forgotten a semicolon on line 2 :)

Comment: notice he has some *words* with a space before/after a comma, might want to add trim() to get rid of that

Comment: +1 for making like 7 updates for this

Comment: @RadGH ahahahahaha im useless !